# AADSTS50020: User account does not exist in tenant

Tags: office-addins, azure-ad-graph-api

I was able to register an app created by another tenant as an enterprise app of my own tenant.
I signed in to the app as a user, but I got the following error.

---

AADSTS50020: User account 'test001@testdomain001.onmicrosoft.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee/' does not exist in tenant 'testdomain002' and cannot access the application '55555555-6666-7777-8888-999999999999'(OneDriveAPIBrowser_test001) in that tenant.
The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

---

How can a user of another tenant use it without the application creator tenant performing any processing?

Comment: Which tenant your Azure AD app is registered in? testdomain001 or testdomain002?

Comment: Same error. Except I'm trying to login with the account that's an organization owner. How can an owner who's  a global administrator be not authorized ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Azure AD app is registered in Tenant A and you have add it as an enterprise app into Tenant B, you should use a user from Tenant B to sign in.

In your case, if the registered app is in testdomain001 and added into testdomain002, you need to use a user from testdomain002. User "test001@testdomain001.onmicrosoft.com" is not allowed to sign in to the app in testdomain002 unless it is a guest user of testdomain002.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

My explanation was insufficient.
The relationship is as follows.

Tenant A = testdomain001 = App creator
Tenant B = testdomain002 = App user

The application registration to tenant B was completed by the administrator of tenant B.
An AADSTS50020 error occurred when a tenant B user tried to use the app.

Is there a way to get Tenant B users to use the app with only Tenant B's work?

Comment: @MuneSeiji Thanks for your explanation. But based on your error message, you are using this account 'test001@testdomain001.onmicrosoft.com' which is from Tenant A (not Tenant B) to use the app. Anyway, I think I got your idea. You need to specify the authority as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant B}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` rather than `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant A}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`. And remember to use a user from Tenant B.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Since the app is not intended for a specific tenant, I thought about using'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'.
And I understood that in order to use'common'instead of the tenant ID, it is necessary to create the app correctly.
The app uses'https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-apibrowser-dotnet' as is, but I don't fully understand it.
I still don't understand the authentication API in detail.

Start by familiarizing yourself with the authentication API.

Comment: @MuneSeiji If you need to use `common`, just make sure you need to register the app as multi-tenant app. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/xebls.png.

Comment: @MuneSeiji What are the issue you are facing now? Can you explain it in detail? Based on the information we have discussed, the reason for this issue is that you are using a user from tenant A to sign in. But you should use a tenant B user here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

The app is registered as multi-tenant like your image.
Then, after the administrator of tenant B registers as an enterprise application of tenant B, the user of tenant B is accessing the application.

Comment: @MuneSeiji So this issue is resolved now right? If my answer is helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you:)

Comment: I'm getting another AADSTS50011 error now, but I think I was able to clear the AADSTS50020 error by changing the URL registered as an enterprise app by another tenant administrator.
If you do not understand the AADSTS50011 error, we will ask you a separate question and this matter will be closed.

Comment: @MuneSeiji It's recommended to add a new post with more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the steps below and it worked for me.

1. Go to azure.microsoft.com
2. Select Free Account.
3. Sign in with your email.
4. It will detect that you already have a subscription and give you the option to use it.